# $watch does not fire autocomplete ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have small portion of codes with `$watch` but does not fire when a use input with autocomplete ( jQuery plugin). it only fires when manual typing input

```
app.directive("autoCode", ['elementData', function(elementData) {
    var codes = elementData.map(function(ele){
        return ele.Code;
    });     
    return {
     restrict: 'A',
     scope:{        
     },  
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {     
        $(element).autocomplete({source:[codes]});      
    }};
}]);

app.controller('transactionCtrl',['$scope','elementData', function($scope, elementData){
    var names = elementData.map(function(ele) {
        return ele.Name;
    }),
    codes = elementData.map(function(ele) {
        return ele.Code;
    });

    $scope.$watch('code', function(codeValue){
        console.log(codeValue);

    }); 
}]);
```

below is html:

```
 <form >

    Code: <input type="text" name="code" auto-code ng-model="code">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" auto-name ng-model="name">

    </form>
```

How to make it work with manual typing and autocomplete?

Comment: Hi, please provide a full plunkr

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? So we can debug the problem. It should be your `auto-code` directive is not assigning the model to `code` variable.

Comment: Hi, just provide related portions of codes. Could you pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$scope.$watch($("input[name='code']").length, function(codeValue){
        console.log(codeValue);

    });
```

O something like that. You have to put the watch over a value that is changed for many times